# Disabling Replication and Replicated Tables

Tags: sql-server, replication

We are in the process of collapsing a SQL Server database from 2 databases into 1.  Currently database 1 is the publisher and doing transactional replication to database 2 which is the subscriber.  There are about 20 tables being replicated to database 2.

The question is, once I delete replication, do the tables that are getting replicated to database 2 get deleted?   And if not do they keep their keys, foreign keys etc?